# MySQL statistics Questions formula

Tags: mysql, statistics

I'm trying to see what Questions statistics consists of.

I'm calculating QPS graph for Questions and QPS graph for sum of:

- `Com_select`
- `Com_update`
- `Com_delete`
- `Com_replace_select`
- `Com_set_option`
- `Com_begin`
- `Com_commit`

Basically all non zero Com_* statistics. But still I have up to 200 QPS difference in graphs.

Does anyone know what wasn't taken into account?

I'm using 4.1.22 version of MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some testing on this. I came to know we have missed one more major count.

That is **Qcache_hits**

Include this in the list and you will see almost similar count on both the places.

Answer (score 0):

"Quits" are also taken into account. I can't find it documented, but have tested this to work:

First, I issue two successive checks on `Questions` to test the test itself:

```
root@mysql-5.1.51> show global status like 'questions';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| Questions     | 21113 |
+---------------+-------+

root@mysql-5.1.51> show global status like 'questions';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| Questions     | 21114 |
+---------------+-------+
```

So each invocation like this makes for +1 on `Questions` -- we will reduce this from future tests.

And now, I quit an active session, then test again:

```
root@mysql-5.1.51> show global status like 'questions';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| Questions     | 21116 |
+---------------+-------+
```

I made sure to enable general log so as to test the Quit operation was not issuing any funny queries -- it was not.

I'm not sure if there are any more operations which should be taken into account.

By the way, as of **5.0.72** and **5.1.31** the rules change. [Read this](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/questions-or-queries) for more.

Comment: hm... we are using hibernate to connect DB, I don't think it will create up to 200 qps of quits. But I will check, thank you.

Comment: Seems like it were cache hits